# How to perform an integral with a polynomial and a radical?

Tags: integration

[image]

How did they go from the first step in the blue to the second step in the blue?

I tried integration by parts but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Look for a suitable substitution.

Comment: Is it a trigonometric substitution by any chance?

Comment: No; regular $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\left(x^{2/3}\right)'=\frac23x^{-1/3}\;,\;\;\text{so:}$$

$$\int x^{-1/3}\sqrt{1+x^{2/3}}dx=\frac32\int\left(\sqrt{1+x^{2/3}}\right)'\sqrt{1+x^{2/3}}\;dx=$$

$$=\frac32\frac 23\left(1+x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}=\left(1+x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}$$

We're using here the nice general

$$\int f'\cdot\sqrt f\;dx=\frac23\cdot f^{3/2}$$